Problemas con condiciones if
Estoy teniendo problemas con la lógica en la programación de un sistema de cuotas. Mi idea es que si en el carrito está cargada la cuota anual 2025 no me deje cargar las cuotas 1, 2, 3, ..., 12 de ese año, pero sí las de los años anteriores.
Les dejo el código a ver si me dan una mano:
$cero = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], "conc");
$anio = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], "anito");

if (in_array("CUOTA ANUAL - 2025", $cero) || in_array("2024", $anio)) {
    echo 'puedo subir cuotas 2024';
    return;
}

$cero = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], "conc");

if (in_array("CUOTA ANUAL - 2025", $cero)) {
    echo 'Al Agregar la CUOTA ANUAL, se anula la carga del carrito';
    return;
}

if (!in_array("CUOTA ANUAL - 2025", $cero))
    for ($count = 0; $count < count($iddeuda); $count++) {
        $cart_iddeuda = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        $item_array = array(
            'iddeuda'          =>     $iddeuda[$count],
            'conc'             =>     $conc[$count],
            'monto'            =>     $monto[$count],
            'matricula'        =>     $matricula[$count],
            'venc1'            =>     $venc1[$count],
            'concept_id'       =>     $concept_id[$count],
            'anito'            =>     $anito[$count],
            'deb'              =>     $deb[$count],
            'product_quantity' =>     1
        );
        
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$iddeuda[$count]] = $item_array;
        {
        echo "Items Agregado al Carrito.";
    }


Muchas gracias por su tiempo, un abrazo

¿Cual es el problema específico?

no logro que la condición para cuotas 2024 se entienda, cargo la cuota única 2025 y me sigue permitiendo cargar las individuales 2025, 2024 y lo que quiero es que me carge solo las individuales 2024 y no las individuales 2025 al estar cargada la cuota unica 2025

y cuál es el contenido de $_SESSION['shopping_cart']?

'iddeuda'          =>     $iddeuda[$count],
'conc'             =>     $conc[$count],
'monto'            =>     $monto[$count],
'matricula'        =>     $matricula[$count],
'venc1'            =>     $venc1[$count],
'concept_id'       =>     $concept_id[$count],
'anito'            =>     $anito[$count],
'deb'              =>     $deb[$count],
'product_quantity' =>     1

que se los paso con un post

hace falta realizar una validación más clara y específica sobre las cuotas anuales y mensuales en función del año ... el código le falta alcance y tiene redundancias... voy a mirarlo un rato a ver si te hecho una mano...

Hay que hacer una serie de cambios ...
si "CUOTA ANUAL - 2025" ya está en el carrito. Si está presente, se impide la carga de cualquier cuota individual del 2025.
Permitir cuotas individuales de años anteriores, como 2024, sin restricciones.
Durante la iteración de las cuotas ($iddeuda), se debe verificar si se intenta agregar una cuota del 2025 mientras la anual del 2025 está en el carrito. Si es así, se salta la iteración correspondiente.
SE deberia agregar mensajes específicos para cada caso, haciendo más comprensible el flujo del codigo.
Ejmplo:
// Obtenemos los valores de 'conc' y 'anito' del carrito actual
$cero = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], "conc"); // Lista de conceptos
$anio = array_column($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], "anito"); // Lista de años

// Verificamos si la cuota anual 2025 ya está en el carrito
if (in_array("CUOTA ANUAL - 2025", $cero)) {
    echo 'La CUOTA ANUAL 2025 ya está en el carrito, no se pueden agregar cuotas individuales de 2025.';
    return;
}

// Verificamos si hay cuotas de años anteriores (por ejemplo, 2024)
if (in_array("2024", $anio)) {
    echo 'Se pueden cargar cuotas individuales de 2024.';
}

// Iteramos sobre las deudas para agregar al carrito
for ($count = 0; $count < count($iddeuda); $count++) {
    $cart_iddeuda = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    
    // Verificamos si estamos intentando agregar cuotas individuales del 2025
    if ($anito[$count] == 2025 && in_array("CUOTA ANUAL - 2025", $cero)) {
        echo "No se pueden agregar cuotas individuales de 2025, ya está cargada la cuota anual.";
        continue; // Saltamos este ciclo si se intenta agregar cuotas del 2025
    }

    // Agregar el item al carrito
    $item_array = array(
        'iddeuda'          => $iddeuda[$count],
        'conc'             => $conc[$count],
        'monto'            => $monto[$count],
        'matricula'        => $matricula[$count],
        'venc1'            => $venc1[$count],
        'concept_id'       => $concept_id[$count],
        'anito'            => $anito[$count],
        'deb'              => $deb[$count],
        'product_quantity' => 1
    );
    
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$iddeuda[$count]] = $item_array;
    echo "Item agregado al carrito: " . $conc[$count] . " del año " . $anito[$count] . ".<br>";
}

